# Laravel Backpack select2 1-n in repeater field

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

hello I have this structure products have many colors:

| products_table | colorables_table | colors_table |
| --- | --- | --- |
| id | product_id | id |
| name | color_id | name |
| colors |  |  |

I want to store the color quantity for the product, for example product 1 has 2 items of the color  pink and I Tried achieving this by using a repeater field like so:

```
 CRUD::field('colors')->label('Colors')->type('repeatable')->new_item_label('Add Info')->fields([
        [
            'name'       => 'color',
            'label'      => 'Color',
            'type'       => 'select',
            'model'      => 'App\Models\Color',
            'entity'     => 'color',
            'attribute'  => 'name',
            'wrapper'    => ['class' => 'form-group col-md-6 required'],
        ],
        [
            'name'    => 'number',
            'type'    => 'number',
            'label'   => 'Number',
            'wrapper' => ['class' => 'form-group col-md-6 required'],
        ],
    ]);
```

in my product model:

```
 public function color(): BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Color::class, 'colorables', 'product_id', 'color_id');
}
```

the problem is that its not storing in the  **colorables_table** (the product and the color id), its just storing the json from the repeater filed in the **products_table** 
any idea how to solve this ?

Comment: You can use a mutator. We add colors for the product to the crud, and in the mutator we add a field that counts the actual number of colors

Comment: the qty of the color needs to be entered by the user so I cant calculate  it

Answer (score 1):

**SOLVED:** 
To solve the issue I created an *observers* for the Product model 
and in the *Created* function of this *observers* I put the following code:

```
/**
 * Handle the Product "created" event.
 *
 * @param  \App\Models\Product  $product
 * @return void
 */
public function created(Product $product)
{ 
    foreach ($product->colors as $color) {
        $product->color()->attach($color['color_id']);
    }
}
```

and Worked like a charm